# Data mining for gene dataset with pairwise comparison

Tags: data-mining

I have a table of sample a b c's gene data pairwise comparison, but I really don't know how to start data mining for this specific dataset. I wonder if anyone can come up with some idea, maybe in some specific gene perspective.

```
                        p value
        | a vs b | a vs c | b vs c | ...
| gene1 |  0.12  |  0.31  |  0.12  | ...
| gene2 |  0.04  |  0.01  |  0.27  | ...
| gene3 |  0.05  |  0.01  |  0.02  | ...
| gene4 |  0.21  |  0.21  |  0.05  | ...
   ...     ...      ...      ...     ...
```